# SQLAlchemy doesn't work when I create an engine

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a connection with a database as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine("mysql://root:password@localhost/testDB")
con = targetEngine.connect()
```

This is the error message:

```
"Can't load plugin: %s:%s" % (self.group, name)
 sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:mysql
```

The same code was working until a few weeks ago. Ever since I had to reinstall MySQL server and the python packages I've been having this problem.

Comment: Take a look at [the doc](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#mysql) and check you have installed the appropriate python packages

Comment: I  imported **pymysql** instead of **mysql** and it worked fine.

Comment: @PKP did you use engine = create_engine("pymysql://root:password@localhost/testDB") ???

Comment: This is  I used ** database_connection = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://{0}:{1}@{2}/{3}'.format(database_username, database_password, database_ip, database_name))**

Comment: The format is `<dialect> [ + <driver> ] ...`, so it'd be `mysql+pymysql://...`